# Как открыть файлы с помощью программы через контекстное меню, передав параметры через реестр

Tags: windows, cmd, реестр

Есть хорошая программа сбора информ. о видео файлах - avdump.
Чтобы сделать отчёт по всем видео, создаётся .bat в директории с avdump.exe следующего содержания

```
@echo off
%0\..\avdump.exe %* -log:%1.avdump.txt
```

Но проблема в том, что файлы нужно перетаскивать на батник. Кроме того мне нужно оформить отчёт в теги - с этим я справился.
Проблема в том что я хочу выделить все файлы, скажем .mp4 расширения, нажать ПКМ
и в контекстном меню выбрать пункт о создании файла.
Как добавить пункт и запустить в программе я понял, но как передать параметры (аргументы) работы программы никак не могу понять.
Вот сделал файл реестра, который добавляет запись в реестр. На 4й строке - путь к программе, с помощью которой будет сделан отчёт.
Как прикрутить параметры, указанные кодом выше?

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.mp4\Shell\avdump]
@="Сделать отчёт avdump"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.mp4\Shell\avdump\Command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Десктоп\\ПРОГРАММЫ\\avdump\\avdump.exe\" \"%*\""
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.mp4\Shell\avdump\Command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Десктоп\\ПРОГРАММЫ\\avdump\\avdump.exe\" \"%*\""
_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.mp4\Shell\avdump\Command]
```

Не рабочий вариант:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.mp4\Shell\avdump\Command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Десктоп\\ПРОГРАММЫ\\avdump\\avdump.exe\" \"%*\" \"-log:%1.avdump.txt\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, так просто передать множество файлов невозможно.

Варианты решения:

1. Добавить пункт в меню "Отравить" (SendTo)
   `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`
2. Найти готовую программу, которая создает [Shell extension](https://rsdn.ru/article/winshell/shlext1.xml) и позволяет добавлять свои пункты, например [FileMenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/filemenutools). Она поддерживает множество аргументов, запуск от имени администратора и много еще чего полезного. Позволяет использовать как вложенное подменю, так и добавлять пункты в основное меню. Можно установить русский интерфейс.
3. Я [набросал прогу на С++](https://github.com/zenden2k/context-menu-launcher) , которая собирает все аргументы воедино и запускает нужную команду ([скачать скопилированный .exe, подписанный моим сертификатом](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/zenden/zenden-image-uploader/singleinstance.exe))

Пример использования:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.mp4\Shell\avdump]
"MultiSelectModel"="Player"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.mp4\Shell\avdump\Command]
@="singleinstance.exe \"%1\" \"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Десктоп\\ПРОГРАММЫ\\avdump\\avdump.exe\" $files \"-log:%1.avdump.txt\" --si-timeout 400"
```

Comment: Не хотелось бы прибегать к стороннему ПО, т.к. теряется смысл труда.  FileMenu Tools действительно делает пункт в popup меню, но не там где нужно.

Comment: @akxmed боюсь, что без доп. ПО у вас это не получится сделать, ведь эксплорер для обычных пунктов меню запускает отдельную копию приложения для каждого выделенного файла. Придется  писать программу или скрипт, который будет отлавливать повторные запуски, использовать IPC (Inter-Process Communication) чтобы передавать параметры и в конце запустит нужную команду, собрав все аргументы воедино.

Comment: @akxmed можете попробовать использовать мою прогу singleinstance, которая собирает файлы и запускает нужную команду. Добавил пример в свой ответ.

Comment: >ведь эксплорер для обычных пунктов меню запускает отдельную >копию приложения для каждого выделенного файла.

Comment: Спасибо. Это предложение было самым полезным. Я думал что через "%1" передаётся массив путей к файлам в приложение, но с учётом этого тезиса, всё встаёт на свои места. Каждая запись из массива передаётся в свою копию программы. Попробую Вашу прогу на С++.

Comment: Спасибо большое очень помогло.